# ¿Como doy permiso para que vea una maquina virtual?

Tags: azure

Quiero asignar un recurso especifico, no quiero que entre con mi cuenta ¡Help!

Comment: ¿que clase de acceso intentas dar?, ¿puedes ampliar un poco?

Comment: que ingrese a la maquina virtual y haga cambios

Comment: http://www.hyper-v.nu/archives/hvredevoort/2013/12/assigning-owner-and-user-role-to-vms-in-windows-azure-pack/

Comment: Gracias, di permisos como se que la otra persona tiene esos permisos, si me reporta que aun no le llega ningún aviso. Lo que hice mas rapido fue darle el IP, el usuario y pass de la VM claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea una cuenta de invitado y dale los permisos correspondientes.